# server parameter not specified in myapp?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

i got the message: server parameter not specified in myapp?

What is the server parameter used for?  Can you give me some examples of its use?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. You are more likely to get your questions answered if you explain the problem at had, as specifically as possible, and also provide code samples, etc where applicable

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have just started with appengine python
The quick start is actually pretty good, just follow the instructions and you should be fine

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld